# What is the connection between runid and testcase in TFS?

Tags: tfs, testcase

Can anyone please explain me about the run id in TFS since currently I am using one of the TFS API to get the testcase outcome using this runid and the thing is I don't have that much knowledge regarding runid and all.

So please tell me what does exactly runid mean? how it related to test case? Does TFS generate new runid if we update something on testcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Test Case you are configure a case - Steps with action and Excepted result.

When you want to check the case, you need to "run" the test case, after it you will have run id.

How do you run the cases and see the test runs history? click on the "Test" tab, and then choose on "Test Plans", now you will see the Test Suits with the Test Cases. you can choose a Test Case and click "Run":

[image]

After you will complete the run you can do the "Runs" tab and see the history and the "Run ID":

[image]

So, for conclusion, when you test the Test Case (it can be multiple times) you get a new Run ID (exist under the "Runs" tab).